# Octave or Matlab code for iterative selection of the columns of a matrix

Tags: arrays, matrix, octave

I have a matrix `A` composed of 4 columns `C1`, `C2`, `C3` and `C4`.
I would like to have all the matrices (vectors) that can be generated from matrix `A` without repetitions of columns and where the order of the columns does not matter, i.e. matrix `B = [C1 C2] = [C2 C1]` . More precisely I would like to obtain the following matrices / vectors: `[C1]; [C2]; [C3]; [C4]; [C1 C2]; [C1 C3]; [C1 C4]; [C2 C3]; [C2 C4 ]; [C3 C4]; [C1 C2 C3]; [C1 C2 C4]; [C1 C3 C4]; [C2 C3 C4]; [C1 C2 C3 C4]`.

How can I do this in octave?

Comment: Do you need a loop that sequentially provides those matrices? Or to build a cell array containing all of them? Must the matrices be produces in the order in your example, or is any order acceptable?

Comment: In the body of the question you ask explicitly for Octave code, but the title and tags suggest you would accept MATLAB code as well. These two are not the same. It is possible to write code that works in both, but in general, code written for one doesn’t run in the other without changes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is MATLAB code to do it using logical indexing and arrayfun:

```
n = size(A,2); % number of columns
x = logical(dec2bin(1:2^n-1)-'0'); % logical array of all possible combinations
C = arrayfun(@(k)A(:,x(k,:)),1:size(x,1),'uni',false); % build the combinations
```

Result will be in the cell array C. Basically, each row of the dec2bin result is used for logical indexing into the columns of A. Note that this method is only practical for relatively small values of n. For large n the memory requirements quickly become overwhelming.

Comment: Maybe it's more readable to use `x = dec2bin(1:2^n-1)~='0';`, or better yet `x = dec2bin(1:2^n-1)=='1';`